# How to register scripts in the startup/scripts folder if they are inside a Sub-folder?

Tags: python, scripting, customization, startup-file

I know I can place a script in Blender's startup/scripts folder and it will register when you open Blender, which is what I normally do.

However, I have a lot of scripts so I tried putting them in a sub-folder, but now Blender doesn't register any of them, it just can't see them. I would really like to use folders for organization purposes.

**What would I need to make my scripts register from their sub-folder?**

Maybe some sort of ****init**.py** at the startup/scripts level (outside any subfolder) that does something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the script path in the file paths section of user preferences.

[image]

Comment: Won't that override the current scripts path?